# How do I record and run multiple find/replace with Sublime Text 2?

Tags: windows-7, windows, automation, text-editors, sublime-text-2

How do I record and run multiple find/replace with Sublime Text 2? I tried recording a macro but, as it seems, Sublime won't record find/replace, only text input etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, Reg Replace is the way to do it. After installing that package, the way to do it is:

1. Edit <your Sublime Text Directory>/Packages/RegReplace/reg_replace.sublime-settings (you can access this in ST2 at Preferences > Package Settings > Reg Replace > Settings – Default). Create new entries in the "replacements" object, each one being a single regex find/replace. Note that you have to doubly escape special characters. For example,

> ```
>     {
>     "replacements": {
>         "do_something_1": {
>         "find": "\\s*\\t\\s*",
>         "replace": "\\t",
>         "greedy": true,
>         "case": false
>     },
>         "do_something_2": {
>         "find": "\\n\\n+",
>         "replace": "\\n",
>         "greedy": true,
>         "case": false
>     },
>     ...
> ```

2. String those individual replacements together into a command for the Command Palette. To do this, edit the file <your Sublime Text Directory>/RegReplace/Default.sublime-commands (Preferences > Package Settings > Reg Replace > Commands – Default). Add something like this:

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "caption": "Reg Replace: My RegEx Macro",
>         "command": "reg_replace",
>         "args": {
>             "replacements": [
>                 "do_something_1",
>                 "do_something_2"
>             ]
>          }
>      },
>      ...
> ```

Then all you have to do is invoke the command palette by hitting Ctrl+Shift+P and browse to your newly created command.

For reference, on my Windows 7 installation, the Sublime Text directory is at C:/Users//AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/

Comment: I did find a way to edit the Default.sublime-commands from the menu. Preferences -> Package Settings -> Reg Replace

Comment: Aha. Post updated.

Comment: @JohnAlexander, Thanks.  Having to figure _that_ out on my own - was as likely to happen as getting my brain surgery degree.

Comment: @JohnAlexander if RegReplace get updated automatically by Package Control, will the settings and commands remain?

Comment: @Edward yes, I believe so.

Comment: The package has been updated so that rules go in a dedicated file (`reg_replace_rules.sublime-settings`) instead of in the package settings file (`reg_replace.sublime-settings`).  You can get to the new file by going to Preferences > Package Settings > Reg Replace > Rules - User.  Also, I believe user commands belong in the user version of the command file, not in the "default" version of it, though either probably works.  Other things to note: you don't need to escape backslashes in the "replace" values, and I found that I didn't need to specify "greedy" or "case".

Answer (score 1):

You're right Sublime will not record find/replace.

However from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656560/batch-find-and-replace-for-sublime-text-2) on Stackoverflow, it appears you can use [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace).

Answer (score 0):

We don't need Plugins. Here is the sublime text macro code to replace "War" with "Love".

```
[
    {
        "args": {"to": "bof"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "args": {"characters": "War"}, "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args": {"extend": true, "to": "bol"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "command": "slurp_find_string"
    },
    {
        "args": {"characters": "Love"}, "command": "insert"
    },
    {
        "args": {"extend": true, "to": "bol"}, "command": "move_to"
    },
    {
        "command": "slurp_replace_string"
    },
    {
        "args": null, "command": "left_delete"
    },
    {
        "args": {"close_panel": true }, "command": "replace_all"
    },
]
```